# ラベルによって色が変わる折れ線グラフを書きたい

Tags: python3, r, matplotlib

ある行に値とそのラベルがそれぞれ保存されているデータを折れ線グラフとして表示したいです。
そのとき、値ごとに振られているラベルで色を分けて表示したいです。

下図は、作りたいグラフのイメージ図です。
[image: 書きたいグラフのイメージ]

横軸がデータのインデックス、縦軸がデータの値、線の色がデータのラベルという対応にしたいと考えています。
このようなグラフを、PythonかRで作るとすれば、どのようにスクリプトを記述すればいいでしょうか?

参考にしたサイト
[データの値で色を変える方法](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html)
[散布図で色を変える方法](https://teratail.com/questions/130617)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下Rとggplot2パッケージ(tidyverseパッケージに含まれる)による例です。

```r
library(tidyverse)

dt <- data.frame(
  x = 1:4, 
  y = c(4, 2, 3, 4),
  label = c("a", "b", "a", "a"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

print(dt)
#>   x y label
#> 1 1 4     a
#> 2 2 2     b
#> 3 3 3     a
#> 4 4 4     a

dt %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  # group = 1としておくことで1本の線としてつなげる
  # group optionを抜くとlabelごとに線が引かれます
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, group = 1, colour = label))
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

matplotlib であれば、こんな感じで書けます。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [4.3, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
label = [0,1,0]

cmap = ListedColormap(['b', 'r'])

points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1,1,2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap)
lc.set_array(np.array(label))

ax =  plt.subplot()
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.set_xlim([1,4])
ax.set_ylim([0,5])
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: 出力結果]